# turn a string into plist - swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, plist

Looks like I might be the only one attempting this, or its so easy everyone but me already knows how!

Website request returns a plist response, the response is received as a string.  How do I then get that plist "string" into a dictionary?

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://...")
let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerasdfsalfkjlksjdfy"
let contentType = "mulutipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)
var dataString = ""
let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
var error: NSError? = nil
let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

let results = NSString(data: reply!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

results is a plist string with xml header and data following plist structure.  the plist return works well if I use

```
NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: path)!)!
```

however, I'm posting, not 'getting' so I can't use NSURL path as far as I know.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the plist is XML you could try using NSXMLParser to build your data structure from it. Alternatively libxml or many 3rd party Obj-C XML parsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSPropertyListSerialization` is your friend here, so long as you're truly getting back plist data:

```
if let plistData = results.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true) {
    var format = NSPropertyListFormat.XMLFormat_v1_0
    let options = NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.Immutable
    if let dict = NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(plistData, 
                                      options: NSPropertyListReadOptions(options.rawValue),
                                       format: &format, 
                                        error: nil) as? NSDictionary {
        println(dict)
    }
}
```

Comment: i get an error 'NSPropertyListFormat' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $t7'

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
if let plistData = results(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true) {
    var format = PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.xml
    let options = PropertyListSerialization.MutabilityOptions.mutableContainers
    if let dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData,
                                                          options: PropertyListSerialization.ReadOptions(rawValue: options.rawValue),
                                                   format: &format) as NSDictionary {
        print(dict)
    }
}
```

Comment: add some comments in your code for better understanding